# Animation timing does not execute properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a small personal website for practice purposes and I came across something that I can`t resolve.

I am having a div which on click flips, expand size and move left.
But there is a nasty glitch that happens only in the begining and I can`t figure out why.

Below is the codepen. If everything works fine for you refresh it again till you see the glitch in the animation.

https://codepen.io/pasaden/pen/RyWBNq

**When in codepen go to full site view to be able to see it.**

That is the glitch I am seing sometimes

[glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fa6OX.jpg)

[glith2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEsx9.jpg)

```
  <div class="wrapper">

    <section class="container">
      <div id="card">
        <figure class = "front">
        </figure>
        <figure id = "backOfCard" class = "back"></figure>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
```

```
    .wrapper{
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("bcgImg.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  display: none;

}

section.container { 
  position: relative;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 40%;
  height: 200px;
  perspective: 500px;
  margin-left: -100%;
}

#card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;

}

#card figure {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s;
  height: 100%;
}

#card .front {
  border: 2px solid #ffeedd;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(85, 85, 51,0.5);
  transition: 0.8s;

}
#card .back {
  background: #ddbb33;
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
}

#card.flipped {
  transform: rotateY( 180deg );
}

#backOfCard.flipped{
 transform: rotateY( 0deg ); 
}

#card figure.front:hover{
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 30px black;
  transition: box-shadow 0.6s;
}
```

And that`s my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#card").click(function(){
    var container= $("section.container");

            $("div#card").addClass("flipped").one(transitionEvent,function(event){
                container.animate({height: '100%'}).animate({marginLeft: '0',width: '300px'});;  
            });
       });
});
```

**UPDATE**
I noticed it mainly happens when I load the page for the first time.If I restart the page , the animation plays normally

Comment: cant reproduce. OS X, Chrome Version 66.0.3359.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: You don`t see the glitch?

Comment: No. I've updated 10 times.

Comment: That`s strange. I will wait to see if other people can reproduce it.

Comment: When you are trying in codepen go to the full site view, otherwise you won`t see the glitch

Comment: And I noticed that the glitch appears when the animation is loaded for the first time.If you refresh after that, there are no issues.